# This program is meant to work with the spotify api to find the top songs of artists and i have no idea what is causing this error in my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, spotify

I looked up a YouTube tutorial on how to find artists top tracks on Spotify through Python but when I was running it errors came up that weren't appearing in the comment section.

Forgive me if this is simple; I just got into programming in general 2 days ago.

https://youtu.be/WAmEZBEeNmg?si=DCGzFYN9BlVduW6R (youtube link for reference)

``````py
import base64
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import base64
from requests import post, get

load_dotenv()
import json

Client_ID = "00000000000000000000000000000000"

Client_S = "000000000000000000000000000000000"
client_id = os.getenv("Client_ID")
client_secret = os.getenv("Client_S")


def get_token():
    auth_string = Client_ID + ':' + Client_S
    auth_bytes = auth_string.encode("utf-8")
    auth_base64 = str(base64.b64encode(auth_bytes), "utf-8")

    url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + auth_base64,
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-urlencoded"
    }
    data = {"grant_type": "client_credentials"}
    result = post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    json_result = json.loads(result.content)
    token = json_result["access_token"]
    return token


def get_auth_header(token):
    return {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token}


def search_for_artist(token, artist_name):
    url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search"
    headers = get_auth_header(token)
    query = f"q={artist_name}&type=artist&limit=1"

    query_url = url + "?" + query
    result = get(query_url, headers=headers)
    json_result = json.loads(result.content)["artists"]["items"]
    if len(json_result) == 0:
        print("no artist with this name exists")

    return json_result[0]


def get_songs_by_artist(token, artist_id):
    url = f"https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/{artist_id}/top-tracks?country=US"
    headers = get_auth_header(token)
    result = get(url, headers=headers)
    json_result = json.loads(result.content)["tracks"]


token = get_token
result = search_for_artist(token, "ACDC")
artist_id = result["id"]
songs = get_songs_by_artist(token, artist_id)
print(songs)

for idx, song in enumerate(songs):
    print(f"{idx + 1}, {song['name']}")`````
``````

Here are the other errors but they look like they will be fixed if the first one is fixed.

> 

````
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\zyrex\PycharmProjects\Soptify to youtube to mp3\main.py", line 60, in <module>
        result = search_for_artist(token, "ACDC")
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\zyrex\PycharmProjects\Soptify to youtube to mp3\main.py", line 40, in search_for_artist
        headers = get_auth_header(token)

 File "C:\Users\zyrex\PycharmProjects\Soptify to youtube to mp3\main.py", line 35, in get_auth_header
    return {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token}
                             ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "function") to str
```
>
````

Comment: Is that the complete traceback?  It seems to be missing the actual error message.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it so i might be mistaken but it seems that on line 59 `token = get_token`, you are not calling the get_token() function as it misses the parenthesis. Try replacing it with `token = get_token()` and see if it works better.

Comment: it now displays this as one of the errors

>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zyrex\PycharmProjects\Soptify to youtube to mp3\main.py", line 59, in <module>
    token = get_token()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\zyrex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\zyrex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               
>

Comment: these are the other 2 it cut out

>

  File "C:\Users\zyrex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\zyrex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

>

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `get token` code

From

```
def get_token():
    auth_string = Client_ID + ':' + Client_S
    auth_bytes = auth_string.encode("utf-8")
    auth_base64 = str(base64.b64encode(auth_bytes), "utf-8")

    url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + auth_base64,
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-urlencoded"
    }
    data = {"grant_type": "client_credentials"}
    result = post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    json_result = json.loads(result.content)
    token = json_result["access_token"]
    return token
```

To

```
def get_token():
    url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    data = { "grant_type": "client_credentials", "client_id": Client_ID, "client_secret": Client_S}
    result = post(url, data=data)
    json_result = json.loads(result.content)
    token = json_result["access_token"]
    return token
```

##### Demo code

```py
from requests import post, get
import json

Client_ID = "*************** your client ID ***************"
Client_S = "*********** your client secret ***********"

def get_token():
    url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    data = {"grant_type": "client_credentials", "client_id": Client_ID, "client_secret": Client_S}
    result = post(url, data=data)
    json_result = json.loads(result.content)
    token = json_result["access_token"]
    return token

def get_auth_header(token):
    return {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token}

def search_for_artist(token, artist_name):
    url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search"
    headers = get_auth_header(token)
    query = f"q={artist_name}&type=artist&limit=1"

    query_url = url + "?" + query
    result = get(query_url, headers=headers)
    json_result = json.loads(result.content)["artists"]["items"]
    if len(json_result) == 0:
        print("no artist with this name exists")

    return json_result[0]

def get_songs_by_artist(token, artist_id):
    url = f"https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/{artist_id}/top-tracks?country=US"
    headers = get_auth_header(token)
    result = get(url, headers=headers)
    json_result = json.loads(result.content)["tracks"]
    return json_result

token = get_token()
# print(token)

result = search_for_artist(token, "ACDC")
artist_id = result["id"]
# print(artist_id)

songs = get_songs_by_artist(token, artist_id)

for idx, song in enumerate(songs):
    print(f"{idx + 1}, {song['album']['name']}")
```

##### Result

[image]

##### Album Name depth checking by Postman

Why I change sone iteration depth

```
for idx, song in enumerate(songs):
    print(f"{idx + 1}, {song['album']['name']}")
```

`URL`

```
https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/{artist-id}/top-tracks?country=US
```

`Token Assign`
[image]

`Response body`
[image]